# Check all enabled trace events

Tags: oracle-12c, trace

Recently  on a database I enabled trace for event `12842` using the below statement in order to trace Oracle error `ORA-12842` : Invalidated cursor.

```
alter system set events '12848 trace name ERRORSTACK level 3';
```

After sometime the error did occur but we could not find any trace file for that event.

I am suspecting the tracing got disabled after instance restart.

Is there any way to list out all the events for which tracing is enabled ?

Answer (score 2):

I got my answer from the below link: 
[generate/analyze trace for error 1461](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107521/generate-analyze-trace-for-error-1461)

One may know by using the following statements in sqlplus:

```
oradebug setmypid 
oradebug eventdump system
```

This did the magic :)